# SSRS 2012 Conditional Axis Label Formatting

Tags: reporting-services

I have a result set that returns me date\time (at hourly intervals) values which are plotted along my x-axis on a line chart and I am formatting into just the hours (time) parts.

These time values can repeat, so for example:

09:00
10:00
14:00
15:00
18:00
09:00
10:00
12:00

What I would like to be able to do is clearly label along the x axis the date that the same hours parts fall within, so a secondary level of labelling?

I want to keep the hour display formatting along the marks on the x-axis but below these and spanning across them labels for the dates they fall in.

So I imagine:

---

09:00   10:00  12:00  14:00    18:00  09:00  12:00  14:00
           10-Nov-2012               |      11-Nov 2012

I hope this makes sense to someone out there, is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your chart you will already have a Category Group for your Time values.  Add another Category Group for the Dates.